# Forgot to register myself in Russia, now I'm in trouble

Tags: legal, russia, study

I am a student studying in Russia. I just came back from my country 13 days ago. I completely forgot to present my request to reissue the registration thing. Now my university says it’s too late and that I need to leave the country and reenter again for the migration card to be renewed. I cannot travel at this time. So is there any other way to do it? Some suggested that I stay at some hotel. I really need help. Is there a fine to pay or anything else?

**[UPDATE]**: Ended up leaving the country for 1 day and coming back. No issues at passport control. Reissued the Registration successfully. LEGAL IMMIGRANT!

Comment: Register what exactly?

Comment: Where are you currently living? Hotel? Student housing?

Comment: @Berkov L Exiting/re-entering is unlikely to work because your lack of registration will flag up when you attempt to leave. Everything I’ve read about registration states that it is primarily the host’s responsibility, if I were you I’d talk to the university again and ask them what problems their proposed solution might cause you. https://www.visahouse.com/en/information/problemsandsolutions/#q3-4 There’s likely to be a fine and worst case scenario you could be denied re-entry if you don’t regularise the situation.

Comment: I would stay one night in a hotel and let them register you. Your school doesn't want to do it because you are in violation. You shouldn't leave the country, just simply register with an entity that's recognized by the Russian Federation. Like a cheap hotel.

Comment: It's good that you found a way through this within the immigration rules. The idea of 'hiding in a hotel' seems awfully shady to me, and it's hard to imagine Russia's government wouldn't take a similarly dim view.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot help much, but here is some info:

- info in english -> https://spb.hse.ru/en/io/immigration/;
- registration must be performed within 7 days, with a few exceptions for citizens of some ex-USSR countries;
- if you have been staying at a hotel, it must have registered you for the period of your stay, so you have some extra time;
- in case of violation of the migration procedures both you and the accepting organization (university/hotel) may be fined, which is why the university is trying to make sure that everything is clean on their side.